# How to narrow the type of a discriminated union without explicitly enumerating the cases in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, union-types, discriminated-union

So, I find myself to work with discriminated unions quite a bit, and I often encounter this issue:

I have a function with a parameter which type is a discriminated union, and I want to do something if said parameter belongs to a subset of the union

In order to do that, I can use the discriminant to narrow the type, and all is good.

The problem arises when the union grows in size, and I find myself with long chains of `if (x.type === 'a' || x.type === 'b' || x.type === 'c' || ...)`

In Javascript, in such cases I would just `if (['a','b','c'].includes(x.type))`, but this approach doesn't cut it for TS

Here is an example:

```
type Certificate = {
    type: 'NATIONAL_ID',
    nationality: string
} | {
    type: 'PASSPORT',
    passportNumber: string
} | {
    type : 'INSURANCE_CARD',
    provider: string
} | {
    type: 'BIRTH_CERTIFICATE',
    date: string
}| {
    type: 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE',
    date: string
}| {
    type: 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE',
    date: string
}


// Works fine, but requires me to enumerate the discriminant cases one by one
const goodPrintDate = (certificate: Certificate) => {
    if (certificate.type === 'BIRTH_CERTIFICATE' || certificate.type === 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE' || certificate.type === 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE') {
        console.log(certificate.date)
        return
    }

    console.log(`certificate of type ${certificate.type} has no date`)
}


// Doesn't work
const badPrintDate = (certificate: Certificate) => {
    const certificateTypesWithDate = ['BIRTH_CERTIFICATE', 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE', 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE']

    if (certificateTypesWithDate.includes(certificate.type)) {
        // Only gets here if certificate type is 'BIRTH_CERTIFICATE', 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE', or 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE', but TS does not know :( 
        console.log(certificate.date) //Property 'date' does not exist on type '{ type: "NATIONAL_ID"; nationality: string; }'
        return
    }
    
    console.log(`certificate of type ${certificate.type} has no date`)
}
```

So, is there a way for me to improve the syntax of `goodPrintDate` so that I don't need to explicitly enumerate every time? E.g. extracting that logic to a separate function (isCertificateWithDate / isCertificateTypeWithDate)

I've tried doing some type gymnastics, using sets instead of array, but nothing working

Comment: How about using a `switch` statement?

Comment: I guess it would be a bit prettier, but if I have to do the same check in 2 places, then I still have to duplicate the logic. I'd love to move it to a separate function, so I can reuse it

Answer (score 2):

You can simply build a custom [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
// Custom type predicate
function isCertificateWithDate(certificate: Certificate): certificate is BIRTH_CERTIFICATE | DEATH_CERTIFICATE | MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE {
    return ['BIRTH_CERTIFICATE', 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE', 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE'].includes(certificate.type)
}

const goodPrintDate = (certificate: Certificate) => {
    if (isCertificateWithDate(certificate)) {
        console.log(certificate.date) // Okay
        //          ^? (parameter) certificate: BIRTH_CERTIFICATE | DEATH_CERTIFICATE | MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE
        return
    }

    console.log(`certificate of type ${certificate.type} has no date`)
    //                                 ^? (parameter) certificate: NATIONAL_ID | PASSPORT | INSURANCE_CARD
}
```

You could even build a more flexible version with a generic type:

```
// Custom flexible type predicate
function isCertificateType<T extends Certificate['type']>(certificate: Certificate, ...types: T[]): certificate is Certificate & { type: T } {
    return types.includes(certificate.type as any) // certificate.type may definitely not be in T
}

const goodPrintDate2 = (certificate: Certificate) => {
    if (isCertificateType(certificate, "BIRTH_CERTIFICATE", 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE')) {
        console.log(certificate.date) // Okay
        //          ^? (parameter) certificate: BIRTH_CERTIFICATE | MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE
        return
    }

    console.log(`certificate of type ${certificate.type} has no date`)
    //                                 ^? (parameter) certificate: NATIONAL_ID | PASSPORT | INSURANCE_CARD | DEATH_CERTIFICATE
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgggFQJIHl4BkD6SAiUC8UA3gFBTlSiQBcUA5PMmnFrnQDRkUB2AhsAEsA9nwA2A0LQDOwAE4DuAcxIBfEiSrQACnADKurSgBKCAsS7lNtOjv2GTHC1DC8pUsENnAYAVwC2AEYQstJyCspqGuDQSDC6AKpGcDAAwgCimClwRniEpBSU0daxCUmpGVk5jgVgskIAbgIAJsGh8kqq6ppQAEJIJgASmWkmSABiSFkIaWb5FFb0fYPDoxNTadUUTfwQbeGdUZBQOGmIQ+mrk4gzeU4LdCdnK8hr15vk28C7UDLtEV3RKAAWWyRiQcAA4hURi8rtNZncivQQUYwZDoZd1u8oJ9vr99pFuilgoIAGYCADGOzMjFQGGweAAPlBbAZjKZmSVEsl0plskzev0EOcYeM4TNmY9hc8xesoMyUWioTLXtN1AB6dVQFI+GRCPyFI61CBNSk7EiknzcCmCERQARSYleATkqlfADqEgAFjgdgAKCkkl1mr60J1kkMQACUtEDztd1IdguWF1hcslp2lqdl13lwNB4OV2dVMzm5FkEGAPlk3CgAG06Ess6KSxx6FKRZi3uxkQX0SrxXQALoAOgUFNEPhaUgDQYTXxHmijB012t1wH1UFJoggAA8BAEd4boMbTW6IBarTbhLWHeHg+eENEADymPdfbhNKTaueRhuaYcAD5Z3jSMw1-c8exHaDNCkWgEDrIcYygOMI3Pe1v3vedoAAMmIY94KgFRzAKCsqxrY8pDHa1J2nEC0J2RdAVcKBeG4EAoygVdUIfRjuj8XgQBxCByW4CQIFEITuCEYAoCCe1awQA4SApEQZCgRQhCEJotHaYBfS+Mx6N40Mf1A89OPwQCSIoF0oD9O8IJ2T1gB9f0eOwqNOLLAoULUoQdxHUQhEUYzsJHXFONXFAAGtBKcApV18goAD0AH4EooMjq24JxIgKVTuCkAKICCkK-QAAw8yMoCEUljygAASIhqvPJjIGIr0WOknEdgq5dEq1ZLhpG0byHSzpCvUzTtN0hR9J2AAmIzWp2cDzJ2SzrJ8uyHMdJyvifSAwsjHsACIm07NNrjOns6EVQsMWu6Y6C8mzkqmkqytC1aF0iritVi+KRqSkaJpG7Kazy9QCv8wLgtCqqDugOqGua37Ss0TruqEXqvn6pxQbG4nRomlQgA)

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I can think of for your problem is using `switch` with fall-through:

```
const printDate = (certificate: Certificate) => {
    switch (certificate.type) {
        case 'BIRTH_CERTIFICATE':
        case 'DEATH_CERTIFICATE':
        case 'MARRIAGE_CERTIFICATE':
            console.log(certificate.date) 
            return
        default:
            console.log(`certificate of type ${certificate.type} has no date`)
    }
}
```

It does list all relevant cases in a fairly readable way. If you want to explore other type-narrowing options, I recommend to read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html.

Whether `includes` should narrow down types was discussed before, e.g. in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275, but the TS team decided against it as the added complexity is not worth the added value. Feel free to check this out as well for a better understanding of the problem.